# Get API-endpoint and store it in a SQLite (Python)

Tags: python, python-requests

As you can see I am trying to fetch data from this API-endpoint `https://api.coindesk.com/v1/bpi/currentprice.json` and I have chosen few data I want to fetch and store it in SQLite.

When I try to save it in a database it gives me this error:

`Traceback (most recent call last):
File "bitcoin.py", line 41, in <module>
 cur.execute("INSERT INTO COINS (Identifier, symbol, description) VALUES (?, ?, ?);", to_db)
sqlite3.ProgrammingError: Binding 1 has no name, but you supplied a dictionary (which has only names).`

How can I store the some of the data from API-endpoint into the database?

I'm doing this to learn programming and still new to this so hopefully, you can guide me in the right way.

Here is what I have tried so far:

```
import requests
import sqlite3

con = sqlite3.connect("COINS.db")
cur = con.cursor()

cur.execute('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS COINS')

cur.execute(
   "CREATE TABLE COINS (Identifier INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, symbol TEXT, description TEXT);"
)

r = requests.get('https://api.coindesk.com/v1/bpi/currentprice.json')
to_db = r.json() # I do not have to do it in json, CSV would also be another
                 # solution but the data that is been stored cannot be static.
                 # It has to automatically fetch the data from API-endpoint

cur.execute("INSERT INTO COINS (Identifier, symbol, description) VALUES (?, ?, ?);", to_db)

con.commit()
con.close()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import requests
import sqlite3

con = sqlite3.connect("COINS.db")
cur = con.cursor()

cur.execute('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS COINS')

cur.execute(
 "CREATE TABLE COINS (id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENTUNIQUE,  
symbol TEXT, description TEXT);")
r = requests.get('https://api.coindesk.com/v1/bpi/currentprice.json')
to_db = r.json()
des=to_db['bpi']['USD']['description']
code=to_db['bpi']['USD']['code']
cur.execute("INSERT INTO COINS (symbol, description) VALUES (?, ?);",         
(des,code))
con.commit()
con.close()
```

Check full code

Comment: How do you insert the values into SQLite database? Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Now I'm getting this error: 

`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "stack.py", line 18, in <module>
    cur.execute("INSERT INTO COINS (Identifier, symbol, description) VALUES(?, ?, ?);", (des, code))
sqlite3.ProgrammingError: Incorrect number of bindings supplied. The current statement uses 3, and there are 2 supplied.
`

Comment: It works, thank you! But if i want to insert a value with a boolean. What kind of type do you use to represent the key as a boolean in SQLite?